# CSS: creating a certain layout using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a certain layout using bootstrap:

[image]

But unable to achieve 2 main principles in my layout:

1. in the first row, div 2 should be 'sticked' to the bottom of it's column (relayed on div1's height).
2. in the second row, i have 3 divs i want to align at center (while using bootstrap grid system!)

**edit:** regarding the 2nd row: i tried using 3 columns lets say 3-col for each div (since i want the margin on the right and left) but i remain with an offset of 3 more which i cant divide equally. 
so i decided changing it to col-4 with a margined container, that's my solution to it:

```
<div class="container" style="padding: 0 80px;">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div style="border:solid 1px black;">Div1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div style="border:solid 1px black;">Div2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div style="border:solid 1px black;">Div3</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tomico/y7xesq6v/

Hope anyone could explain how can i handle this 2 issues

Comment: 2. Use the traditional method of a wrapper, center that with margin auto, and use the grid system inside it so each div will be 4 columns wide (out of 12). Alternatively you can use the offset class.

Comment: 1. Equalize the columns using a variety of techniques. (Google). Then you can use position absolute at the min-width to get div2 on the bottom. 2. Create another wrapper (like @MatthewRath) suggested. So you can, make a wrapper around the .row then make that wrapper 80% then center it with margin auto.

Answer (score 0):

Would this suffice?

```
.div1{position:relative;margin-top:20px;float:left;}
.div2{position:absolute;float:left;right:0px;top:40px;}
```

As for the 3 div row, i would wrap those three up with another div, to center just that one div containing the other three divs.

```
    // Classes
.center-block {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

// Usage as mixins
.element {
  .center-block();
}
```

from : [Bootstrap Source](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic)

Comment: I dont see how is your solution related to bootstrap grid system at all (more specifically your 2nd row solution)

Comment: second block is copied from the website, first block is custom css

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a margin-top with % for .div2

```
       .div2 {margin-top:50%}
```

---

For your second issue what's been said above will work,
here's how the code should look:

```
<div class="row">
                     <div class="wrap">
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <div style="border:solid 1px black;">Div1</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <div style="border:solid 1px black;">Div2</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <div style="border:solid 1px black;">Div3</div>
</div>
   </div>
```

then add CSS for wrap

```
        .wrap {width:50% ; margin:0 auto } //or 800px or whatever
```